# OS boots but black screen, not even BIOS menu is shown

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, display, hardware-failure, acer-aspire

I have 5 years old Acer Aspire 7741g. I was playing video games and suddenly I got artifacts on screen and screen freezing so I had to reboot. This happened several times in couple of days only during video games playing.

Now suddenly when I start up the screen remains black, not even BIOS option is shown, but I can hear OS stars correctly. If I press F2 I can hear entering BIOS but screen is black.

Is graphics card broken (wouldn't I be able to see and enter BIOS if so)?

Or is monitor backlight broken?

What are other options?

It was on service recently and they said hard disk has some errors, but if it is hard disk I could enter bios.

Comment: One way to determine the problem between the monitor backlight and the GPU is to plug the machine into an external monitor.  If you get output, then its most likely your monitor.  If not, then you may have a GPU issue.

Comment: From the artifacts it looks like GPU, but shouldn't I be able to enter BIOS if GPU is issue?

Comment: Depends, the test I mentioned though would make it clear.  Laptops usually have an integrated GPU.  So if the GPU was truly failing, you would have trouble booting in general, or get no video output.  (Hence why I suggested to plug into an external monitor)